unable to download webpage "https://www.nawaiwaqt.com.pk/national" using curl
I am trying to download this page :
https://www.nawaiwaqt.com.pk/national
using curl.
getting error:
Download un-successful : error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

The code I am using is:
<?php
$url ="https://www.nawaiwaqt.com.pk/national";
function curl_download($Url){
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    if (!$output) {
       exit("Download un-successful : ".curl_error($ch));
    } 
    return $output;
}
// $url is any url
$source=curl_download($url);
$d=new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($source);
$title=$d->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent;
$domx = new DOMXPath($d);
$desc=$domx->query("//meta[@name='description']")->item(0);
$description=$desc->getAttribute('content');
?>


Why did you set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);?

You should use a valid cacert.pem as source for CURLOPT_CAINFO and 2 for CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST

Did you check whether this is really a PHP problem? Maybe running cURL on the shell isn't working either? Also, how is this problem related to [tag:copy]?

I tried the code on my workstation and did see the error you've got. Perhaps it's a machine setup issue instead.

Professor A : I think you are pointing out something important, but I am not sure how to accomplish that, can you direct me to any article abt it?

The website you are visiting might be old due to that it cannot support SSL version 3. In your code, you should allow cURL to use the SSL/TLS version automatically.
Also, the downloaded content might include special characters or encoding that aren't rendered correctly so I have set the correct content type header in code.
<?php
$url = "https://www.nawaiwaqt.com.pk/national";

function curl_download($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // Change 1: Set this to 0 to not include the header in the output
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
 // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); // Removed this
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    if (!$output) {
        exit("Download un-successful: " . curl_error($ch));
    } 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$source = curl_download($url);

// Set the content type to HTML
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
echo $source;


// For testing purpose, I have Save the content to a external html file
file_put_contents('downloaded_page.html', $source);

// Load the HTML for parsing the title and description
$d = new DOMDocument();
@$d->loadHTML($source);
$title = $d->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent;
$domx = new DOMXPath($d);
$desc = $domx->query("//meta[@name='description']")->item(0);
$description = $desc ? $desc->getAttribute('content') : 'No description available';

// Output the title and description
echo "Title: " . $title . "\n";
echo "Description: " . $description . "\n";
?>



I have tested the script on my machine and it works fine as it displays the output of the provided URL in my browser correctly. Moreover, I have also downloaded the content of a provided URL in a external file called downloaded_page.html which also works fine.

I tried your code on my local host and it works there, but not working on Godaddy hosting. getting the error : Download un-successful: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds. I tried increasing the time from 10 to 100 , still same error but for that 100001 milliseconds of time

I tried your suggestions on my local host and it works on localhost.

For Godaddy, try to contact  their technical support. Might be CURL is not installed or there might be some other restriction. I have one suggestion for GoDaddy, change your URL to GoDaddy homepage and then try the script.
